# How to import ScriptableObject asset file into Unity 3d project.

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, assets

I have created ScriptableObject derived Quests.asset file in one of my project and then just copied it into my other project Assets folder. When I click on this file in  project inspector view, I see "the associated script can no be loaded" message. When i create `public Quests quests;` field in my script, there is: "type not found" error. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it. There was C# script with the same name I was missing. When copied to the new project all started to work.